# Activity crashes sometimes when starting the adapter

Tags: android, android-gridview, baseadapter, android-logcat

I got a really strange bug that do not seem to make any sense at all. I got an adapter that seems to just sometime crash at startup. It seems like at almost randomly manage to set an use my custom BaseAdapter from time to time to populate a custom GridView. I start the Actvity by AsyncTask so it is no timeout on the UI thread, and it seems to crash with the about same frequency on a low end as on a high end device. Based on the logcat, the app crashes when I try to get an array from the main Activity class. This is my logcat output:

```
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at my.package.name.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:142)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2470)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1026)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at my.package.name.MyCustomGridView.onMeasure(MyCustomGridView.java:52)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12815)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1047)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:585)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12815)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12815)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12815)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:690)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:583)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12815)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2106)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12815)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1068)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2452)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4493)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
07-04 21:42:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My getView in my CustomAdapter:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

mParentView = parent;

DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;


int box = width/7*6/10;

int boxH = height/7;

int gridS = width/7*6;

ImageCell v = null;
if (convertView == null) {
    // If it's not recycled, create a new ImageCell.
    v = new ImageCell (mContext);
    if(box*7>=height){
         v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(boxH, boxH));
    }
    else{
    v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(box, box));
    }
    v.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    v.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);


} else {
    v = (ImageCell) convertView;
}

v.mCellNumber = position;
v.mGrid = (GridView) mParentView;
v.mEmpty = true;
int id = 200;
v.setId(++id);

String map = str[position]; //line 142
int pos = position;
int up = pos-10;
int down = pos+10;
int left = pos-1;
int right = pos+1;

int le_up = pos-11;
int up_ri = pos-9;
int ri_do = pos+11;
int do_le = pos+9;

if(up>=0){
above = str[up];
}
else{
    above="l";

}
if(down<70){
    under = str[down];
    }
else{
    under="l";

}
if(left<=-1){

    lefte="l";
}

else{
     if(left==9|left==19|left==29|left==39|left==49|left==59){
        lefte="mountain";
    }
     else{
    lefte=str[left];
     }
}
if(right>=70){


    righte="l";
 }     
 else{
     if(right==10|right==20|right==30|right==40|right==50|right==60){
      righte="mountain";
    }
     else{
    righte=str[right];
     }
 }
if(le_up<=-1){
    left_up="l";
 }     
 else{
     if(le_up==9|le_up==19|le_up==29|le_up==39|le_up==49|le_up==59){
        left_up="mountain";
    }
     else{
     left_up=str[le_up];
     }
 }
if(up_ri<=-1){
    up_right="l";
}     
else{
     if(up_ri==10|up_ri==20|up_ri==30|up_ri==40|up_ri==50|up_ri==60){
        up_right="mountain";
    }
     else{
 up_right=str[up_ri];
     }
}
if(ri_do<70){
     if(ri_do==10|ri_do==20|ri_do==30|ri_do==40|ri_do==50|ri_do==60){
     right_down="mountain";
    }
     else{
    right_down = str[ri_do];
     }
    }
else{

    right_down="l";

}
if(do_le<70){
     if(do_le==9|do_le==19|do_le==29|do_le==39|do_le==49|do_le==59){
        down_left="mountain";
        }
     else{
    down_left = str[do_le];
     }
    }
else{

    down_left="l";

}



if (map.equals("mountain")) {
    //Checks surroundings to find out which drawable to set  
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
     v.mEmpty = false;
     //All
     if(above=="mountain"&&under=="mountain"&&lefte=="mountain"&&righte=="mountain"){
         //All edges
         if(left_up!="mountain"&&up_right!="mountain"&&right_down!="mountain"&&down_left!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_edges);
         }
         //One edge
         else if(left_up!="mountain"&&up_right=="mountain"&&right_down=="mountain"&&down_left=="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_edge);
         }
         else if(left_up=="mountain"&&up_right!="mountain"&&right_down=="mountain"&&down_left=="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_up_right_edge);
         }
         else if(left_up=="mountain"&&up_right=="mountain"&&right_down!="mountain"&&down_left=="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_right_down_edge);
         }
         else if(left_up=="mountain"&&up_right=="mountain"&&right_down=="mountain"&&down_left!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_down_left_edge);
         }
         //Two edges
         else if(left_up!="mountain"&&up_right!="mountain"&&right_down=="mountain"&&down_left=="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_right_edge);
         }
         else if(left_up!="mountain"&&up_right=="mountain"&&right_down!="mountain"&&down_left=="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_right_down_edge);
         }
         else if(left_up!="mountain"&&up_right=="mountain"&&right_down=="mountain"&&down_left!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_down_left_edge);
         }
         else if(left_up=="mountain"&&up_right!="mountain"&&right_down!="mountain"&&down_left=="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_up_right_down_edge);
         }
         else if(left_up=="mountain"&&up_right!="mountain"&&right_down=="mountain"&&down_left!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_up_right_down_left_edge);
         }
         else if(left_up=="mountain"&&up_right=="mountain"&&right_down!="mountain"&&down_left!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_right_down_left_edge);
         }
         //Tree edges
         else if(left_up=="mountain"&&up_right!="mountain"&&right_down!="mountain"&&down_left!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_up_right_down_left_edger);
         }
         else if(left_up!="mountain"&&up_right=="mountain"&&right_down!="mountain"&&down_left!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_right_down_left_up_edge);
         }
         else if(left_up!="mountain"&&up_right!="mountain"&&right_down=="mountain"&&down_left!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_down_left_up_right_edge);
         }
         else if(left_up!="mountain"&&up_right!="mountain"&&right_down!="mountain"&&down_left=="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_right_down_edger);
         }
         else {
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.grass);
         }
        }
     //Single
     else if(above=="mountain"&&under!="mountain"&&lefte!="mountain"&&righte!="mountain"){
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_down);
        }
     else if(above!="mountain"&&under=="mountain"&&lefte!="mountain"&&righte!="mountain"){
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_up);
        }
     else if(above!="mountain"&&under!="mountain"&&lefte!="mountain"&&righte=="mountain"){
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left);
        }
     else if(above!="mountain"&&under!="mountain"&&lefte=="mountain"&&righte!="mountain"){
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_right);
        }
     //Double
     else if(above=="mountain"&&under!="mountain"&&lefte!="mountain"&&righte=="mountain"){
         if(up_right!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_down_edge);
         }
         else{
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_down);
         }

        }
     else if(above!="mountain"&&under=="mountain"&&lefte!="mountain"&&righte=="mountain"){
         if(right_down!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_edger);
         }
         else{       
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up);
         }
        }
     else if(above=="mountain"&&under!="mountain"&&lefte=="mountain"&&righte!="mountain"){
         if(left_up!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_right_down_edger);
         }
         else{       
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_right_down);
         }          
        }
     else if(above!="mountain"&&under=="mountain"&&lefte=="mountain"&&righte!="mountain"){
         if(down_left!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_up_right_edger);
         }
         else{       
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_up_right);
         }      
        }
     else if(above!="mountain"&&under!="mountain"&&lefte=="mountain"&&righte=="mountain"){
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_up_down);
        }
     else if(above=="mountain"&&under=="mountain"&&lefte!="mountain"&&righte!="mountain"){
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_right);
        }
     //Triple
     else if(above!="mountain"&&under=="mountain"&&lefte=="mountain"&&righte=="mountain"){
         if(down_left!="mountain"&&right_down!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_right_down_right_down_left_edge);
         }
         else if(down_left=="mountain"&&right_down!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_right_down_right_down_edge);
         }
         else if(down_left!="mountain"&&right_down=="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_right_down_down_left_edge);
         }
         else{       
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_right_down);
         }      
        }
     else if(above=="mountain"&&under=="mountain"&&lefte=="mountain"&&righte!="mountain"){
         if(left_up!="mountain"&&down_left!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_down_left_up_edger);
         }
         else if(left_up=="mountain"&&down_left!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_down_left_edger);
         }
         else if(left_up!="mountain"&&down_left=="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_down_left_up_edge);
         }
         else{       
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_down);
         }                      
        }
     else if(above=="mountain"&&under!="mountain"&&lefte=="mountain"&&righte=="mountain"){
         if(left_up!="mountain"&&up_right!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_right_left_up_right_edge);
         }
         else if(left_up=="mountain"&&up_right!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_right_up_right_edge);
         }
         else if(left_up!="mountain"&&up_right=="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_right_left_up_edge);
         }
         else{       
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_left_up_right);
         }               

        }
     else if(above=="mountain"&&under=="mountain"&&lefte!="mountain"&&righte=="mountain"){
         if(up_right!="mountain"&&right_down!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_up_right_down_up_right_down_edge);
         }
         else if(up_right=="mountain"&&right_down!="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_up_right_down_right_down_edge);
         }
         else if(up_right!="mountain"&&right_down=="mountain"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_up_right_down_up_right_edge);
         }
         else{       
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain_up_right_down);
         }                  
        }
     //None
        else{
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.mountain);
        }

}

else if(map=="stop"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.oil_tank);
    v.setTag(1);
}
else if(map=="rock"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.mBlowable=true;
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);  
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.rock);    

}
else if(map=="house"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.mBulldozable=true;
    if(righte=="house"){
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.dobble_house_left);   
    }
    else if(lefte=="house"){
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.dobble_house_right);  
    }
    else{
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.single_house);
    }
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
}
else if(map=="norhouse"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.norhouse);
}
else if(map=="gold_pipe_left_right"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.setTag(7913);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.left_right_gold_pipe_empty);
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
}
else if(map=="gold_pipe_up_down"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.setTag(7924);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_down_gold_pipe_empty);
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
}
else if(map=="gold_pipe_left_up"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.setTag(7912);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.left_up_gold_pipe_empty);
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
}
else if(map=="gold_pipe_right_down"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.setTag(7934);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.right_down_gold_pipe_empty);
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
}
else if(map=="gold_pipe_up_right"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.setTag(7923);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_right_gold_pipe_empty);
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
}
else if(map=="gold_pipe_left_down"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.setTag(7914);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.left_down_gold_pipe_empty);
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
}
else if(map=="environmentalists"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.mBribeable=true;
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.environmentalists);
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
}
else if(map=="path"){
    v.mEmpty=true;
    //Full
    if(above=="path"&&under=="path"&&lefte=="path"&&righte=="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_cross);         
    }
    //Single
    else if(above!="path"&&under=="path"&&lefte!="path"&&righte!="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_up);  
    }
    else if(above=="path"&&under!="path"&&lefte!="path"&&righte!="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_down);  
    }
    else if(above!="path"&&under!="path"&&lefte=="path"&&righte!="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_right);  
    }
    else if(above!="path"&&under!="path"&&lefte!="path"&&righte=="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_left);  
    }
    //Double
    else if(above!="path"&&under!="path"&&lefte=="path"&&righte=="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_left_right);  
    }
    else if(above=="path"&&under=="path"&&lefte!="path"&&righte!="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_up_down);  
    }
    else if(above=="path"&&under!="path"&&lefte=="path"&&righte!="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_left_up);  
    }
    else if(above!="path"&&under=="path"&&lefte=="path"&&righte!="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_left_down);  
    }
    else if(above=="path"&&under!="path"&&lefte!="path"&&righte=="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_up_right);  
    }
    else if(above!="path"&&under=="path"&&lefte!="path"&&righte=="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_right_down);  
    }
    //Triple
    else if(above=="path"&&under!="path"&&lefte=="path"&&righte=="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_left_up_right);  
    }
    else if(above=="path"&&under=="path"&&lefte!="path"&&righte=="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_up_right_down);  
    }
    else if(above!="path"&&under=="path"&&lefte=="path"&&righte=="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_left_right_down);  
    }
    else if(above=="path"&&under=="path"&&lefte=="path"&&righte!="path"){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path_left_up_down);  
    }
    else{
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.path);
    }
}

else if(map=="tree"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.mCutable=true;
    if(righte=="tree"){
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.small_leaf_tree_left);    
    }
    else if(lefte=="tree"){
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.small_leaf_tree_right);   
    }
    else{
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.small_leaf_tree);
    }
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
}
else if(map=="water"){
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.mBridgeable = true;
     v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
    //All
     if(above=="water"&&under=="water"&&lefte=="water"&&righte=="water"){
         //All edges
         if(left_up!="water"&&up_right!="water"&&right_down!="water"&&down_left!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_edges);
         }
         //One edge
         else if(left_up!="water"&&up_right=="water"&&right_down=="water"&&down_left=="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_up_c);
         }

         else if(left_up=="water"&&up_right!="water"&&right_down=="water"&&down_left=="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_up_right_c);
         }
         else if(left_up=="water"&&up_right=="water"&&right_down!="water"&&down_left=="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_right_down_c);
         }
         else if(left_up=="water"&&up_right=="water"&&right_down=="water"&&down_left!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_down_left_c);
         }

         //Two edges
         else if(left_up!="water"&&up_right!="water"&&right_down=="water"&&down_left=="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_up_right_c);
         }
         else if(left_up!="water"&&up_right=="water"&&right_down!="water"&&down_left=="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_up_right_down_c);
         }
         else if(left_up!="water"&&up_right=="water"&&right_down=="water"&&down_left!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_down_left_up);
         }
         else if(left_up=="water"&&up_right!="water"&&right_down!="water"&&down_left=="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_up_right_down_c);
         }
         else if(left_up=="water"&&up_right!="water"&&right_down=="water"&&down_left!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_up_right_down_left_c);
         }
         else if(left_up=="water"&&up_right=="water"&&right_down!="water"&&down_left!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_right_down_left);
         }

         //Tree edges
         else if(left_up=="water"&&up_right!="water"&&right_down!="water"&&down_left!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_up_right_down_left);
         }
         else if(left_up!="water"&&up_right=="water"&&right_down!="water"&&down_left!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_right_down_left_up);
         }
         else if(left_up!="water"&&up_right!="water"&&right_down=="water"&&down_left!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_down_left_up_right);
         }
         else if(left_up!="water"&&up_right!="water"&&right_down!="water"&&down_left=="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_up_right_down);
         }


        }

     //Single
     else if(above=="water"&&under!="water"&&lefte!="water"&&righte!="water"){
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_down);
        }
     else if(above!="water"&&under=="water"&&lefte!="water"&&righte!="water"){
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_up);
        }
     else if(above!="water"&&under!="water"&&lefte!="water"&&righte=="water"){
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left);
        }
     else if(above!="water"&&under!="water"&&lefte=="water"&&righte!="water"){
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_right);

     }



     //Double
     else if(above=="water"&&under!="water"&&lefte!="water"&&righte=="water"){
         if(up_right!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_down_up_right_csa);
         }
         else{
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_down);
         }

        }
     else if(above!="water"&&under=="water"&&lefte!="water"&&righte=="water"){
         if(right_down!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_up_right_down_csa);
         }
         else{       
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_up);
         }
        }
     else if(above=="water"&&under!="water"&&lefte=="water"&&righte!="water"){
         if(left_up!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_right_down_left_up_csa);
         }
         else{       
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_right_down);
         }          
        }
     else if(above!="water"&&under=="water"&&lefte=="water"&&righte!="water"){
         if(down_left!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_up_right_down_left_csa);
         }
         else{       
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_up_right);
         }      
        }
     else if(above!="water"&&under!="water"&&lefte=="water"&&righte=="water"){
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_up_down);
        }
     else if(above=="water"&&under=="water"&&lefte!="water"&&righte!="water"){
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_right);

        }

     //Triple
     else if(above!="water"&&under=="water"&&lefte=="water"&&righte=="water"){
         if(down_left!="water"&&right_down!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_up_right_down_left_cs);
         }
         else if(down_left=="water"&&right_down!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_up_right_down_cs);
         }
         else if(down_left!="water"&&right_down=="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_up_down_left_cs);
         }
         else{       
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_right_down);
         }      
        }

     else if(above=="water"&&under=="water"&&lefte=="water"&&righte!="water"){
         if(left_up!="water"&&down_left!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_right_left_up_down_left_cs);
         }
         else if(left_up=="water"&&down_left!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_right_down_left_cs);
         }
         else if(left_up!="water"&&down_left=="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_right_left_up_cs);
         }
         else{       
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_up_down);
         }                      
        }

     else if(above=="water"&&under!="water"&&lefte=="water"&&righte=="water"){
         if(left_up!="water"&&up_right!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_down_left_up_right_cs);
         }
         else if(left_up=="water"&&up_right!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_down_up_right_cs);
         }
         else if(left_up!="water"&&up_right=="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_down_left_up_cs);
         }
         else{       
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_up_right);
         }               

        }

     else if(above=="water"&&under=="water"&&lefte!="water"&&righte=="water"){
         if(up_right!="water"&&right_down!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_up_right_down_cs);
         }
         else if(up_right=="water"&&right_down!="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_right_down_cs);
         }
         else if(up_right!="water"&&right_down=="water"){
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_left_up_right_cs);
         }
         else{       
             v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_up_right_down);
         }  

     }
     //None
        else{
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.water_full);
        }



}
else if(map=="start"){

    v.setTag(2);
    List<String> posOf = Arrays.asList(str);
    startPos=posOf.indexOf("start");
    curPipe=startPos;
    v.mEmpty=false;
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass);
    grid = GameProjectActivity.gridView;
    final ImageCell over =(ImageCell)grid.getChildAt(startPos-10);
    over.mEmpty=false;
    getDur();

     //Had to remove some imports to lower number of characters

     int delay=GameProjectActivity.startDelay;  
     final int signalDelay=delay-3500;

     AnimationDrawable loop = new AnimationDrawable(); 
     loop.addFrame(first, duration);
     loop.addFrame(first, duration);
     loop.addFrame(first, duration);
     loop.setOneShot(false);

    final AnimationDrawable ani = new AnimationDrawable(); 
       ani.addFrame(first, delay);
       ani.addFrame(first, duration);
       ani.addFrame(second, duration);
       ani.addFrame(third, duration);
       ani.addFrame(fourth, duration);

       ani.setOneShot(true);
     v.setImageDrawable(ani);        
       checkIfAnimationDone(ani); 
    v.post(new Runnable() {   
        public void run() {
               ani.start();
                }
        });
    final AnimationDrawable anima = new AnimationDrawable();       
    anima.addFrame(frame2, 200);
    anima.addFrame(frame3, 200);
    anima.addFrame(frame4, 200);
    anima.addFrame(frame5, 200);
    anima.addFrame(frame6, 200);
    anima.addFrame(frame7, 150);
    anima.addFrame(frame8, 150);
    anima.addFrame(frame1, 500);

    anima.setOneShot(false);

    over.setImageResource(R.drawable.oil_tower_top);
    Handler handler = new Handler();

         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            over.setImageDrawable(anima);
               anima.start();

                }
        },signalDelay);

}


return v;
```

}

Please notify me if I need to post more code from my project!
Edit: Most of my code does not make sense, but it is a part of level generating system.

Comment: Looks like getView() returns null or something in getView() throws that exception. Could you post the getView() method of your adapter?

Comment: @LJoosse Took some time due to character overload, but my getView is now posted.

Comment: If `String map = str[position]` is line 142, only `str` can be null. Are you sure it is not null?

Comment: It is not null when setAdapter is called. I populate the array based on a level system that checks a SharedPreference.

Comment: @LJoosse I managed it to avoid crash by adding an empty array, but this makes my system load an empty level :(

Comment: It is hard to say for me when it becomes null. I would make `str` private, create a getter/setter for it and place a breakpoint in the setter. That way, you can see when `str` will get null.

Comment: Also, I suggest you load the drawables you need in the constructor of you adapter and set the drawable like `setImageDrawable()` or something like that. I lost the name of the right method. That way, drawables are not more than once in memory.

Comment: Solved it! It sometimes returned null because i used == instead of .equals() to compare. Silly mistake, but I solved it atleast.